# Sweetalet no funciona bien al eliminar un registro de una tabla

Tags: php, javascript, sweetalert

Tengo un dataTable con un botón de eliminar y estoy implementando la librería de sweetalert. El problema es  que al dar clic en el boton eliminar muestra la venta modal del sweetalerty pero no elimina.

¿Cuál puede ser el problema?

**El Código**

```js
//============== Las liberías ==============

<script type="" src="plugins/datatables/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

// ========= El botón ===============

<a href="#" onclick="confirmDelete()" title="Eliminar" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn btn-danger btn-sm"></a>

//======= El javaScript ==============

<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmDelete() {
    swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function (isConfirm) {
        if (!isConfirm) return;
        $.ajax({
            url: "ruta-donde-elimino.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                id: 5
            },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function () {
                swal("Done!", "It was succesfully deleted!", "success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                swal("Error deleting!", "Please try again", "error");
            }
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

```js
// código d ela clase personaData.php

public function del(){
  $sql = "delete from ".self::$tablename." where idPersona=$this->idPersona";
  Executor::doit($sql);
 }
  
  
  //Código d ela clase persona-action.php
  
  else if (isset($_GET["opt"]) && $_GET["opt"]=="del"){
 $persona = new personaData();
 $persona->idPersona = $_GET["idPersona"];
 $persona->DEL();
 header("Location: ./?view=persona&opt=all");
}
```

La duda que tengo cómo sería la url donde dice: **url: "ruta-donde-elimino.php",** teniendo en cuenta la forma en que elimino los registros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que para que funcione tal cual como quieres tienes que usar ajax, no conozco ni veo la forma de hacerlo así como lo tienes

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo todo mal, porque tienes un enlace que ejecuta la accion de salir de tu entorno y al mismo tiempo ejecutar el alert, lò que debes hacer es eliminar la redireccion del enlace y pasarla a alert:

```
<a href="#" title="Eliminar" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn btn-danger btn-sm eliminar"></a>
```

y en el alert, detectamos el clic y pedimos la confirmacion:

```
$(".eliminar").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  swal({   title: "¡El registro será eliminado permanentemente!",   
    text: "¿Estás seguro de proceder?",   
    type: "warning",   
    showCancelButton: true,   
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
    confirmButtonText: "¡Eliminar Registro!",   
    cancelButtonText: "¡No Eliminar!",   
    closeOnConfirm: false,   
    closeOnCancel: false }, 
    function(isConfirm){   
        if (isConfirm) 
        {   
            //Envio la eliminación
            window.location.href="./?action=persona&opt=del&idPersona=<?=$per->idPersona;?>"

        } 
        else {     
            //Cancelo al eliminacioon
            swal("Hurray", "Account is not removed!", "error");   
        } });
})
```

Comment: Lo arregle como dices, pero ahora no me abre la ventana modal

Comment: y donde queda el mensaje que dice que el mensaje se elimino con exito

Comment: ya me funciona, solo que cuando elimina el registro la ventana con este mensaje desaparece en menos de 2 segundos, como hago para que sea el usuario quien la cierre, donde debo coloca esta linea.    swal("Registro Eliminado!", "", "success");

Comment: amigo, en ese caso deberías de utilizar una petición ajax en vez de un re-direccionamiento para realizar la tarea y así manipular de una mejor manera las alertas y mensajes que requieres